# How to add an element to the existing ImmutableSet - AutoValue?

Tags: java, auto-value

```
Class Event {
  String eventName;
  Integer eventTime;
  ....
  // Event attributes with a builder
}

@AutoValue
public abstract class XYZ {

  public abstract ImmutableSet<Event> events();
  public abstract Event event();
  
  public static Builder builder() {
    return new AutoValue_XYZ.Builder();
  }

  @AutoValue.Builder
  public abstract static class Builder {
    public abstract Builder setEvents(Set<Event> events);
    public abstract Builder setEvent(Event event);

    public abstract XYZ build();
  }
}
```

**Usage:**
End user can add event as a single item or a set of items like below,

```
XYZ xyz = XYZ
    .builder()
    .setEvent(Event.builder().setEventName("event1").setEventTime(34324343).build())
    .setEvent(Event.builder().setEventName("event2").setEventTime(45324343).build())
    .setEvents(
        Set.of(Event.builder().setEventName("event3").setEventTime(55324343).build(),
                Event.builder().setEventName("event4").setEventTime(65324343).build())
    .build();
```

I would like to have all the `event inputs` in the `events()` Set, like everytime `setEvent` is used, add it to the main Set `events()`. How to achieve this?

Eg: `xyz.events() should give 4 events in this case.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by:

1. Using the AutoValue support for creating builders for collections
2. Implementing helper functions on the builder

```java
@AutoValue
public abstract class XYZ {

    public abstract ImmutableSet<Event> events();

    public static Builder builder() {
        return new AutoValue_XYZ.Builder();
    }

    @AutoValue.Builder
    public abstract static class Builder {

        public Builder addEvent(Event event) {
            eventsBuilder().add(event);
            return this;
        }

        public Builder addAllEvents(Iterable<? extends Event> events) {
            eventsBuilder().addAll(events);
            return this;
        }

        public abstract XYZ build();

        protected abstract ImmutableSet.Builder<Event> eventsBuilder();
    }
}
```

Optionally you can also make the `eventsBuilder` method public if you want to give direct access to the builder and not add the helper methods. The advantage of the helper methods is that they can return the `XYZ.Builder` and thus allow chaining.